# Parsing .txt file in C code

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

I've got to parse a .txt file like this

```
autore: sempronio, caio; titolo: ; editore: ; luogo_pubblicazione: ; anno: 0; prestito: 0-1-1900; collocazione: ; descrizione_fisica: ; nota: ;
```

with `fscanf` in C code.
I tried with some formats in `fscanf` call, but none of them worked...

EDIT:

> a = fscanf(fp, "autore: %s");

This is the first try I did; the patterns 'autore', 'titolo', 'editore', etc. must not be caught by `fscanf()`.

Comment: Can we see your code? We are most luckily to help you out with coding issues instead of just programming it for you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)  It is hard to know what could be going wrong when we don't know where you see the boundaries in what you're parsing.  The whole text seems to be on one line; using `fgets()`, you can read the whole line.  But presumably, you want more details than that.  You might be dealing with `<word> <colon> <optional-comma-separated-list-of-words> <semi-colon>`, where you want the single word and the list scanned into variables (and a second operation will split the comma-separated list), or ...

Comment: code added in question ^^" I realized I missed some details

Comment: Even with your amended question, you are still missing a lot of details!

Comment: What's the difference between 'autore' and 'sempronio'?  Do you want to see 'sempronio'?  Or do you need 'sempronio, caio' as a single input?  Do you know that 'autore' will always precede 'titolo' (and there'll be no other entries between the two)?  What exactly are you hoping to extract from the single long line of input that you showed.  Or is it in fact spread over multiple lines?

Comment: 'autore', 'titolo', 'editore', 'luogo_pubblicazione', 'anno', 'prestito', 'collocazione', 'descrizione_fisica', 'nota' are TAGS and they must be in this specific order with the only exception that the 'autore' tag can be repeatet more than once.
'sempronio, caio' is only an example of an author's name ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, trying to parse input with `fscanf` is not a good idea, as it is difficult to recover gracefully if the input does not match expectations. It is generally better to read the input into an internal buffer (with `fread` or `fgets`), and parse it there (with `sscanf`, `strtok`, `strtol` etc.). Details on which functions are best depend on the definition of the input format (which you did not give us; example input is *no* replacement for a formal specification).

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how to use `strtok`:

```
char* item;
char* input; // fill it with fgets

for (item = strtok(input, ";"); item != NULL; item = strtok(NULL, ";"))
{
    // item loops through the following:
    // "autore: sempronio, caio"
    // " titolo: "
    // " editore: "
    // ...
}
```

The following shows how to use `sscanf`:

```
char tag[20];
int chars = -1;

if (sscanf(item, " %19[^:]: %n", tag, &chars) == 1 && chars >= 0)
{
    printf("%s is %s\n", tag, item + chars);
}
```

Here, the format string consists of the following:

- (space) - tells the parser to discard whitespace
- 19 - maximum number of bytes/chars in the tag
- [^:] - tells the parser to read until it meets the colon character
- : - tells the parser to discard the colon character
- (whitespace) - as above
- %n - tells the parser to report the number of bytes it read (check &chars)

If there was an unexpected input, the number of chars is not updated, so you have to set it to `-1` before parsing each item.